# Mapstruct mapping query :mapping an attribute from dto to entity but not an attibute on dto

Tags: java, entity-framework, mapstruct

I have a entity object called TripEvent (persistence entity) .. see below the field i would like to draw attention to is createdby and the list
List

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIPEVENT")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@tripeventId")
public class Tripevent implements Serializable {

...
...

 @Id
 @SequenceGenerator(name = OracleConstants.TRIPEVENT_TRIPEVENTID_GENERATOR, sequenceName = OracleConstants.TRANSACTIONSEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = OracleConstants.TRANSACTIONSEQUENCE_ALLOCATION_SIZE)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = OracleConstants.TRIPEVENT_TRIPEVENTID_GENERATOR)
 @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
 private long tripeventid;


 @Column(precision = 10)
 private Long activitytypeid;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
 private String alertind;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
 private String completedind;

 @Column(nullable = false)
 private Timestamp createdate;

 @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
 private String createdby;
....
....
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripevent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
 @JsonManagedReference(value = "tripevent-fishgear")
     private List<TdfiFishgear> tdfiFishgears;
.....
....
```

The TdfiFishGear class looks like the below snippet, again you can see a created by attribute.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TDFI_FISHGEAR")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@fishgearId")
public class TdfiFishgear implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


 @Id
 @SequenceGenerator(name = OracleConstants.TDFI_FISHGEAR_TDFIFISHGEARID_GENERATOR, sequenceName = OracleConstants.TRANSACTIONSEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = OracleConstants.TRANSACTIONSEQUENCE_ALLOCATION_SIZE)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = OracleConstants.TDFI_FISHGEAR_TDFIFISHGEARID_GENERATOR)
 @Column(name = "TDFI_FISHGEARID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
 private long tdfiFishgearid;


 @Column(precision = 8)
 private Long avghookcount;


 @Column(precision = 15, scale = 3)
 private BigDecimal avgnetheight;


 @Column(precision = 10)
 private Long avgnetheighuomid;


 @Column(precision = 15, scale = 3)
 private BigDecimal avgnetlength;


 @Column(precision = 10)
 private Long avgnetlengthuomid;


 @Column(nullable = false)
 private Timestamp createdate;


 @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
 private String createdby;


 @Column(precision = 6, scale = 1)
 private BigDecimal fishingdepth;


 @Column(nullable = false, precision = 10)
 private Long geartypeid;


 @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
 private String inactiveind;


 private Timestamp lastchangedate;
```

My DTO class Dep which is popluated via Json payload of a restful call looks like this...

```
public class Dep   {

  public Dep(){  
  }

  @NotEmpty(message = "seqNo: is a required field")
  @JsonProperty("seqNo")
  private String seqNo = null;


  @NotNull(message = "depTStamp: is a required field")
  @JsonProperty("depTStamp")
  private ZonedDateTime depTStamp = null;


  @NotEmpty(message = "port: is a required field")
  @JsonProperty("port")
  private String port = null;


  @JsonProperty("nonEUPort")
  private String nonEUPort = null;


  @NotEmpty(message = "activity: is a required field")
  @JsonProperty("activity")
  private String activity = null;


  @JsonProperty("comments")
  private String comments = null;


  @JsonProperty("spe")
  @Valid
  private List<DepSpe> spe = new ArrayList<DepSpe>();


  @JsonProperty("gea")
  @Valid
  private List<NonFarGea> gea = new ArrayList<NonFarGea>();


  public Dep seqNo(String seqNo) {
    this.seqNo = seqNo;
    return this;
  }
```

You can see if this DTO that there is no field called created by .. so on my mapping class you will see what i had to do, there are various calls to mappes which convert codes to ids etc etc

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring",
uses = {
 ZonedDateTimeStampMapper.class, 
 ConfigMapperFromCode.class,
 RasDepMapper.class
 },
 unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE
)


public interface DepToTripEventMapperApi {


 /*root mapper from a dep dto to a entity trip event*/

 @Mappings(
  {
    @Mapping(target = "createdby", source = "regUserId"),
    @Mapping(target = "createdate",expression = "java(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()))"),
    @Mapping(target = "inactiveind", constant = "N"),
    @Mapping(target = "eventtypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "returnDepEventId"}),
    @Mapping(target = "activitytypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "activityIdFromCode"}, source="depDto.activity"),
    @Mapping(target = "marineportid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "portIdFromCode"}, source = "depDto.port"),
    @Mapping(target = "alertind", constant = "N"),
    @Mapping(target = "eventnote", source = "depDto.nonEUPort"),
    @Mapping(target = "ersseqno", source = "depDto.seqNo"),
    @Mapping(target = "skippercomment", source = "depDto.comments"),
    @Mapping(target = "tdfiErsmessageid", source = "messageId"),
    @Mapping(target = "startdate", source = "depDto.depTStamp"),
    @Mapping(target = "completedind", constant = "N"),
    @Mapping(target = "vessel", source = "vessell"),
    @Mapping(target = "triplogs", source = "tripLogs"),
    @Mapping(target = "lastchangedate", ignore = true),
    @Mapping(target = "lastchangedby", ignore = true),
    @Mapping(target = "tdfiCatchmovements", ignore = true),
    @Mapping(target = "tdfiFishgears", source="depDto.gea"),
    ..
  }
 )
 Tripevent DepDtoToTripEvent(Dep depDto, String regUserId, Long messageId, Vessel vessell, List<Triplog>tripLogs);



 // mapper from nonnfargea to fishing gear
 @Mappings(
 {
 @Mapping(target = "meshdimension", source = "gea.gearDims"),
 @Mapping(target = "geartypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "gearIdFromCode"},  source = "gea.gearType"),
 @Mapping(target = "avgnetheight", source = "gea.avNetHeight"),
 @Mapping(target = "avgnetlength", source = "gea.avNetLength"),
 @Mapping(target = "meshsize", source = "gea.meshSize"),
 @Mapping(target = "avghookcount", source = "gea.avHooks"),
 @Mapping(target = "totnetquantity", source = "gea.noNets"),
 @Mapping(target = "tothookscount", source = "gea.totHooks"),
 @Mapping(target = "totnetlength", source = "gea.totLen"), 
 @Mapping(target = "trawltypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "speciesIdFromCode"},  source = "gea.trawlType")
 }
 )
 TdfiFishgear geaToFishGear(NonFarGea gea);

....
...
```

So there are fields outside the dto object that are required in the entity objects, the mapping is working perfectly aside from these fields.

So i am trying to figure out how i can populate a list of tdfiFishgears from depDTo.gea to include a createdby field that is not on the dto but is required on all instances in the list. I have fudged this at the top level by passing them in as parameters of the method(interface).. i dont want to have to provide a custom mapper to loop through the list and instantiate and mapp the objkects manually as, the mapping is working 100% apart from this field(s .. i have more of them).

Any ideas...i should also mention that the DTO layer cannot be changed as it is from another team.

Here is an image of the error i am getting in the ide...[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAyvc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to use `@AfterMapping`, `@BeforeMapping` together with the latest 1.2.0 (not yet final, at the time of the post Beta2 is out) `@Context` hooks so you can populate those fields.

It will look something like:

```
class ExtraFields {

    private String createdBy;
    //Getters omitted
}

public interface DepToTripEventMapperApi {

    //Your mappings
    Tripevent DepDtoToTripEvent(Dep depDto, String regUserId, Long messageId, Vessel vessell, List<Triplog>tripLogs, @Context ExtraFields extra);

    //Your mappings
    TdfiFishgear geaToFishGear(NonFarGea gea, @Context ExtraFields extra);

    @AfterMapping
    default void afterMapping(@MappingTarget TdfiFishgear fea, @Context ExtraFields extra) {
        fea.setCreatedBy(extra.getCreatedBy());
    }
}
```

If you don't want to have the `@AfterMapping` in your interface, you can also include it in the Context object.

Like:

```
class ExtraFields {

    private String createdBy;

    public ExtraField(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterFishGear(@MappingTarget fishGear) {
        fishGear.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i am getting a compile error after this change ...the trip event mapper no longer recognizes the geaToFishGear mapper when i add the @Context parameter to its interface... Can't map property "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.iec3.model.NonFarGea> gea" to "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.ifis.orm.entity.logsheet.TdfiFishgear> tdfiFishgears". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.ifis.orm.entity.logsheet.TdfiFishgear> map(java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.iec3.model.NonFarGea> value)".   It is a list of tdfiFishGears .

Comment: You need to add the `@Context` to all the mappers that are using the `geaToFishGear ` mapper, not just the mapper itself. Are they in the same mapper or in different ones? Did you add the `@Context` to the `DepDtoToTripEvent` as well?

Comment: Hi.. i added to all mappers (2), there are 2 mappers one that maps a trip-event object (which contains a list of gears) and a mapper that maps the gear instances in the list...

Comment: 'TdfiFishgear geaToFishGear(NonFarGea gea, @Context String regUser);'

Comment: 'Tripevent DepDtoToTripEvent(Dep depDto, Long messageId, Vessel vessell, List<Triplog>tripLogs, String regUser, @Context String regUser);'

Comment: I will try out your example tonight and let you know. Maybe it is some bug. You are using 1.2.0.Beta2, right?

Comment: Hi Filip, yes using version 1.2.0.Beta2. I saw in release notes for this version that some problems with @Context and nested classes was addressed...

Comment: Hey Fordey, I just tested the example code you have in the question with my answer and it works as expected. Can you perhaps create some reproducer where it is failing?

Comment: Hi.. the code isnt failing it is not getting that far :-(

Comment: 'Tripevent DepDtoToTripEvent(Dep depDto, Long messageId, Vessel vessell, String regUser, @Context ExtraFields extra);'

Comment: i am getting a error ...Can't map property "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.iec3.model.NonFarGea> gea" to "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.ifis.orm.entity.logsheet.TdfiFishgear> tdfiFishgears". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.ifis.orm.entity.logsheet.TdfiFishgear> map(java.util.List<ie.gov.agriculture.iec3.model.NonFarGea> value)".

Comment: i have added an image of error in ide ..  [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAyvc.png

Comment: I have created https://github.com/filiphr/mapstruct-examples/tree/stackoverflow-reproducer/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles in my girhub repository. Can you have a look at it and see that you are doing it the same. You can clone it and do the mapping like you have it currently